# Using SwiftUI View as UIImage for rendering MKAnnotation error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uiimage

**Update**:
Since I'm using iOS16, could I do something with https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-convert-a-swiftui-view-to-an-image?

---

So I am experiencing some errors on my end, and I wanted to see if anyone could spot anything off with the way that I am doing things.

So this is the error that I am getting:

> 2022-11-05 20:48:52.650233-0500 [2347:488099] [Snapshotting] Rendering
> a view (0x12c9d6800,
> *TtGC7SwiftUI14_UIHostingViewGVS_15ModifiedContentGS1_GS1_GS1_VS_5ImageVS_18_AspectRatioLayout_GVS_11_ClipEffectVS_9Rectangle__GVS_30_EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierGSqVS_5Color___GVS_16_OverlayModifierGS1_GS1_VS_4TextVS_13_OffsetEffect_GS6_GSqS7*______)
> that has not been committed to render server is not supported.

I am creating a `SwiftUI View` as an image and then using that image to render out a `MKAnnotationView`. By the looks of it, I must be doing something wrong, but I can't pin point if exactly.

So let's say that my view looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct LandmarkPin: View {
    var isAnnotationSelected = false
    var body: some View {
        Image("map-pin-full-cluster-1")
            .renderingMode(.template)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            .clipped()
            .foregroundColor(self.isAnnotationSelected ? .red : Color("LandmarkAnnotation"))
            .overlay(
                Image(systemName: "building.columns.fill")
                    .font(.system(size: 10, weight: .bold))
                    .offset(y: -8)
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
            )
    }
}
```

That view gets called inside the MapView:

```
final class LandmarkAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
    var place: Place?
    override func prepareForDisplay() {
        super.prepareForDisplay()
        image = LandmarkPin(
            isAnnotationSelected: (place?.show ?? false)
        ).takeScreenshot(
            origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
            size: CGSize(width: 35, height: 35)
        )
    }
}
```

Then I am using two helper extensions to help me achieve this:

```
extension View {
    func takeScreenshot(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
        let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)
        let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
        hosting.view.frame = window.frame
        window.addSubview(hosting.view)
        window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        hosting.view.backgroundColor = .clear
        return hosting.view.renderedImage
    }
}

extension UIView {
    var renderedImage: UIImage {
        let rect = self.bounds
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)
        let ctx: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        UIColor.clear.set()
        ctx.fill(bounds)
        drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        layer.render(in: ctx)
        let capturedImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        return capturedImage
    }
}
```

Could anyone spot what the error might be hinting at?